# check the nested check box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wirking on html5 with jquery. I want to check the check box based on condition using jquery. Actually my check box is nested in  one  tags.And the respective  is children for one main  tag.Here actually i am trying to loop the main or parent  for finding the children  and sub nested check box.But i am not able to check the check box even if the condition also true.

I have tried with this below code for achieving my goal please help me out.

```
<div class="hello">    
<div class="a">
    <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox1" value="a"/>
    <span class="s">a</span>
</div>
<div class="a">
<input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox11" value="b"/>
    <span class="s">b</span>
</div>
<div class="a">
<input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox1" value="c"/>
    <span class="s">c</span>
</div>
<div  class="a">
<input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox1" value="d"/>
    <span class="s">d</span>
</div>
```

And my scripting is like below

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var stri='';
    stri='a,b';

    var array=[];
    array=stri.split(',');


    $('.hello').children('div').each(function () {     

        var compare=$('.hello').children().has('.checkbox11').text();


             for(var j=0;j<array.length;j++)  
             {
                 alert(compare+" and"+array[j]);
                 alert(compare==array[j]);
                 if(compare==array[j]){
                    $('.hello').children().has('.checkbox11').checked=true;    
                 }
             }

    });
});
```

Comment: Which checkboxes do you want to mark as "checked" and why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but look at this

First of all this is kind of deprecated

```
$('document').ready(function() {});
```

Use this instead:

```
$(function() {});
```

---

If you are using jQuery, use it. You can find you elements like this:

```
var $hello = $('.hello'); // parent div
var $checkboxes = $hello.find('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

---

You can loop all checkboxes like this:

```
$checkboxes.each(function() {
    var $checkbox = $(this);   
    var text      = $checkbox.next().text();
});
```

---

If you want to check if value exists in array you can use [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)

```
if ($.inArray(text, array) > -1)
```

---

You can set checked attribute like this:

```
$checkbox.attr('checked', true);
```